# UITableView: Weird lines when leaving UISearchBar via Cancel Button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, keyboard, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView. I need to have spacing between the cells, so what I did is, that all the cells are sections and the space between is the section footer. Also I have a UISearchBar on top of the table data to search the data.
Now there is one little bug.

I click on the SearchBar. When I do not do a search, but just click cancel directly is get weird lines in the main table view. See Picture 1 below.

When I do a search and scroll the search results and then click cancel the bug doesnt appear.
When I do a search and do not scroll, but click cancel, the bug does appear.

Anyone has an idea where that might come from?

I tried to do setNeedsDisplay and reloadData when the cancelButton is clicked, but neither worked.

Here is the code for the section footers.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section        {
    return kZellenAbstand;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return view;
}
```

[Picture 1 http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4877/iossimulatorbildschirmf.png](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4877/iossimulatorbildschirmf.png)

Comment: I have narrowed it down. If I comment out      view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
the bug does not appear, but the background of the table view, is visible, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: actually, the bug still appears, just isn't visible du to the standard clearColor background.  However, I figured out, that the bug appears to be triggered by the disappearing Keyboard in some cases. The disappearing keyboard for some reason triggers viewForFooterInSection on sections 3 - 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a workaround, at least for my scenario.

Since I only use the footers to have spacing between the cells, I just switched to the headers for that.

As for the issue itself, I issued a bug report with Apple. I'll post here, if I have additional information from that.

Comment: If this is the answer that worked for you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, to indicate to future viewers what worked for you.